# Why was my answer deleted?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

I answered the question that the original user posted with a perfectly correct answer.  He asked about sage dps.

The answer I gave him was correct according to my empirical experience.

Answer (score 6):

This is the question: [What strategy gives the highest DPS for a low-level Jedi Consular?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67323/what-strategy-gives-the-highest-dps-for-a-low-level-jedi-consular/70977#70977)

Moderators respond to flags submitted by users.  In this case, a user familiar with the question and the game flagged your answer as "not an answer" - and a moderator (Juan) intervened by removing it.

Contrary to popular belief, there's not anything particularly personal about deleting content; we're just cleaning things up that have been marked by the community as in need of attention.  We handle on the order of 2,000 flags in a month, and I'd like to think our overall error rate is fairly low.

If you think something has gone wrong in the system, reporting it is fine.  Meta threads are generally best.  We can review the decision and determine if it requires any further action.  Hostility towards the moderators or other users isn't going to produce positive results, however.

Comment: As someone that isn't familiar with the game, it seems like the answer does address the question (though the actual strategy is buried towards the end).